# Snowflake:Epoch to Timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: Convert Epoch to Timestamp

Issue: It is converting into local timezone

When I have checked manually at online it is as below

[image]
[image]

When I tried in Snowflake it is as
[image]

Expected output is
`2017-12-15 09:21:15 | 2017-12-19 14:21:59`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get a timestamp from epoch is `TO_TIMESTAMP()`. But if you also want to work with timezones, you'll need a timestamp with timezone. For that, use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()`.

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1513347675), TO_TIMESTAMP(1513711319)
 , TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(1513347675), TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(1513711319)

# 17-12-15 14:21
# 17-12-19 19:21
# 17-12-15 09:21
# 17-12-19 14:21
```

--

Complete example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_TZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZHTZM';

ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'Etc/GMT';
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(1513347675);
-- 17-12-15 14:21 +0000

ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'US/Eastern';
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(1513347675);
-- 17-12-15 09:21 -0500

ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'US/Pacific';
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(1513347675);
-- 17-12-15 06:21 -0800
```

Comment: I tried it with TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ, it showed me the same output as TO_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Check the complete example that I added to the answer